# android ContactsContract query to show in listview

Tags: android

i am querying contacts through

```
private Cursor cursor;
private static final String SORT_ORDER = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ";

String[]   myProjection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, 
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, 
            ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED};

cursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, myProjection, null, null, SORT_ORDER);
```

and its giving me all contacts details.But my issue is its showing contacts with no entries as well.I want to query and show only those contacts which have at least an email or phone number .If contacts have no phone or email attached to it i dont want to show in my list view. What selection parameters should i need to give to filter them in my query.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After query for your requirement use something like this:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
{
 //show in Listview
 }
 else
  {
  Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",new String[]{id}, null); 
  if(emailCur.moveToNext())
    {
     //show in Listview
    }
  }
```